# Nodejs and mongodb: File Management

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm a beginner at Nodejs.
What I want to do is, upload a file (not an image file), like a .txt, .c, .py, and store it in the mongodb database. I also want to be able to retrieve the file and access the file contents, like what is written inside those files.

I hope the made some sense.

Here is the html script I used to upload a file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
    initial=scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>FILE UPLOAD DEMO</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Single File Upload</h1>
    <form action="/upload"
        enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
            <span>Upload File</span>
            <input type="file" name="myfile" required/> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
    
</html>
```

I'd really appreciate if you helped me out on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/). There's a whole ton of GridFS tutorials out there ([example](https://data-flair.training/blogs/mongodb-gridfs-tutorial/)) but it's also worth noting that if you're certain that your files will be smaller than 16 megabytes, you can also just store the files as a part of BSON documents, which allow you to store binary data ([ref](https://alexmarquardt.com/2017/03/02/trade-offs-to-consider-when-storing-binary-data-in-mongodb)).

Comment: hey thanks brother! It helped a lot! Wish I could've replied sooner.